# Media codec flv play in Windows Phone 7 in Media Element

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, flv, mediaelement, windows-phone-7.1

I want to streaming flv video in Media Element in WP7. I can play wmv format but flv not. I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). So MediaElement doesn´t support flv right? Is there a way how can I play this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. WP7 doesn't support Flash Video.

The only solution available is to convert the video. I'd recommend doing this off the device and not trying to do the conversion on the phone.

Comment: Conversion could be little problem. I want to stream video in flash format from a movie web and there is no other format. User have information about movie in phone (title, cast, genre, ...) and in one pivotitem I want to show trailer but it is in flash video.

Comment: Then you'll need to accept that this is something that the platform can't currently do.